# Algorithm - find the minimal subtraction between sum of two arrays

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic

I am hunting job now and doing many algorithm exercises. Here is my problem:

---

Given two arrays: *a* and *b* with same length, the subject is to make |sum(a)-sum(b)| minimal, by swapping elements between *a* and *b*.

---

Here is my though:

assume we swap a[i] and b[j], set Delt = sum(a) - sum(b), x = a[i]-b[j]
then Delt2 = sum(a)-a[i]+b[j] - (sum(b)-b[j]+a[i]) = Delt - 2*x,
then the *change* = |Delt| - |Delt2|, which is proportional to |Delt|^2 - |Delt2|^2 = 4*x*(Delt-x),

Based on the thought above I got the following code:

---

```
Delt = sum(a) - sum(b);
done = false;
while(!done)
{
    done = true;
    for i = [0, n)
    { 
        for j = [0,n)
        {
            x = a[i]-b[j];
            change = x*(Delt-x);
            if(change >0)
            {
                 swap(a[i], b[j]);
                 Delt = Delt - 2*x;
                 done = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

However, does anybody have a much better solution ? If you got, please tell me and I would be very grateful of you!

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to "Given an array a with length 2*n and sum(a)=2*S, find exactly n elements in the array whose total is as close as possible to S."

Comment: This looks like the knapsack problem in disguise.

Comment: @n.m. more like the partition problem, as Mark mentioned... but there is additional constraint: same number of elements...

Comment: @amit: I'm not sure how it is even like the partition problem with the same number of elements constraint. I see a "take exactly one element from each pair" constraint, not "take exactly one half of all elements" constraint. The two might be equivalent, but probably in some non-trivial way.

Comment: @amit: Oops, I haven't realized that one is allowed to swap elements at different positions. This is a different problem indeed. If the TS have invented the problem himself, then so be it; if not, I'd guess the intent of the problem author is to allow swapping the elements at the same position only. It's much more natural this way.

Comment: I still believe OP misunderstood the problem, and that it is only allowed to swap elements at same positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is basically the optimization problem for [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) with an extra constraint of equal parts. I'll prove that adding this constraint doesn't make the problem easier.

[NP-Hardness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) proof:

Assume there was an algorithm `A` that solves this problem in polynomial time, we can solve the [Partition-Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) in polynomial time.

```
Partition(S):
for i in range(|S|):
   S += {0}
   result <- A(S\2,S\2) //arbitrary split S into 2 parts
   if result is a partition: //simple to check, since partition is NP.
     return true.
return false //no partition
```

**Correctness:**

If there is a partition denote as (S1,S2) [assume S2 has more elements], on iteration |S2|-|S1| [i.e. when adding |S2|-|S1| zeros]. The input to `A` will contatin enough zeros so we can return two equal length arrays: S2,S1+{0,0,...,0}, which will be a partition to `S`, and the algorithm will yield true.

If the algorithm yields true, and iteration `k`, we had two arrays: S2,S1, with same number of elements, and equal values. by removing `k` zeros from the arrays, we get a partition to the original S, so S had a partition.

**Polynomial:**

assume `A` takes `P(n)` time, the algorithm we produced will take `n*P(n)` time, which is also polynomial.

**Conclusion:**

If this problem is solveable in polynomial time, so does the Partion-Problem, and thus P=NP. based on this: this problem is NP-Hard.

Because this problem is NP-Hard, for an exact solution you will probably need an exponential algorith. One of those is simple [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) [I leave it as an exercise to the reader to implement a backtracking solution]

**EDIT**: as mentioned by @jpalecek: by simply creating a reduction: `S->S+(0,0,...,0)` [k times 0], one can directly prove NP-Hardness by reduction. polynomial is trivial and correctness is very similar to the above partion's correctness proof: [if there is a partition, adding 'balancing' zeros is possible; the other direction is simply trimming those zeros]

Comment: I believe you got the indentation wrong - why would you execute `result <- A(S\2,S\2)` n times? BTW what you've written isn't polynomial reduction we use to prove NP-hardness.

Comment: @jpalecek: I am executing `A(S/2,S/2)` once every step, and check for a possible solution with `k` number of zeros, where `k` is the iteration's number. I am not using a reduction here, I am proving that if such an algorithm exist, P=NP, which is equivalent to saying this algorithm is NP-Hard. [because it is clearly NP, and if P=NP then P=NP=NP-Complete]

Comment: The problem is that you must use a reduction to prove NP-hardness, because NP-hardness is defined in terms of reduction. What you've proven is that `Partition \in P^A`, but it doesn't follow (at least not directly) that A is NP complete. Moreover, if you just added all the zeros and asked A once, it would work, too and you'd have a reduction.

Comment: @jpalecek: I editted the answer and added the reduction you had suggested. I am almost certain there is a theorem that if for a certain problem: polynomial solution->P=NP then this problem is NP-Hard [though I cannot recall which theorem, so I might be wrong]. I am thankful for your comment anyway, your suggested reduction is much simpler approach.

Comment: "polynomial solution->P=NP then this problem is NP-Hard". That is almost certainly not true. Consider trivial problem (the one that returns only true). If we assume P=NP, polynomial solution of trivial -> P=NP is true, yet trivial problem cannot be P (or NP) hard. On the other hand, for coNP-complete problems, polynomial solution -> P=NP holds too, but they are not NP-hard. In effect, your theorem would decide the P=NP matter like this: P /= NP = coNP. I'm not saying this is not the truth, but AFAIK it isn't solved yet.

Comment: @amit, This problem is solvable in polynomial time (like Partition) with simple constraint which is acceptable in current PCs, and this doesn't cause to P=NP, your current approach used rarely for this problem in very special circumstance and if some problems seems to be NP-Hard it doesn't mean in all situations. -1 because of your Conclusion part which tries to prevent from further works.

Comment: @jpalacek: I don't see the problem with amit's reduction (although yours is definitely simpler).  According to the Wikipedia page, polynomial-time Turing-reducibility of an NP-complete problem (such as Partition) to the target problem suffices to show that the target problem is NP-hard.  Turing-reducibility allows a polynomial number of calls to the target problem.  Many-one reductions (which allow only a single call to the target problem, at the end) are only needed for NP-completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment. Through all this swapping you can basically arrange the contents of both arrays as you like. So it is unimportant in which array the values are at start.

Can't do it in my head but I'm pretty sure there is a constructive solution. I think if you sort them first and then deal them according to some rule. Something along the lines `If value > 0 and if sum(a)>sum(b) then insert to a else into b`